# git replace --graft loses files when merging unrelated histories

Tags: git

I have two distinct branches b1 and b2, no common ancestor. One adds f1, the other one adds f2.

When I run `git replace --graft <> <>` on them, I can see them sequenced properly using `git log --graph '--pretty=tformat: %H %d %s %n' --all`.

However, if I checkout the resulting branch, at the end of b2, I see a commit that adds f2, as it should, but also *removes* f1, which was added by the parent. Which kinda defeats the purpose since the whole point of this was to have that file along the whole history in all commits (hooks need that).

I tried all variations I could find of rebase, merge, filter-branch, filter-repo. The branch "hierarchy" looks right, but that change removing the file is really getting in the way.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, asking it out loud made me find the answer, and it was embarrassing and obvious. And in the own "documentation"

https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/issues/170

basically use the commit-callback to drop any changes you don't want. Like deleting a specific file, *in any* of the branches.

Comment: Yes. The key to understanding this earlier is to remember that commits represent (and save) *whole snapshots*, and `git replace --graft` just glues the parentage together without changing any of the saved snapshots. You see a file as "deleted" if you compare a snapshot that you put on the left that has the file to a snapshot that you put on the right that lacks the file.

Comment: @torek it's a bit hard to remember that git isn't a sequence of diffs, but rather independent portions of content... the whole commit callback to ignore some file modifications is absolute magic. filter-repo is an _excellent_ tool.